# Tricky regex grouping

Tags: regex, perl

Please consider this regex right there:

```
gene_id\t"(\w+.\d+)"|transcript_id\t"(\w+.\d+)"|gene_name\t"(\w+.\d+)"|transcript_name\t("\S+)
```

And consider this text right behind:

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    183647567       183647797       .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000173627.7"     transcript_id   "ENST00000481562.1"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "APOBEC4"       transcript_type "processed_transcript"  transcript_status       "KNOWN" transcript_name "APOBEC4-002"   exon_number     2       exon_id "ENSE00001907807.1"     level   2       transcript_support_level        "3"     havana_gene     "OTTHUMG00000035459.2"  havana_transcript       "OTTHUMT00000086127.1"
chr1    HAVANA  gene    183646404       183653316       .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000173627.7"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "APOBEC4"               level   2       havana_gene     “OTTHUMG00000035459.2”
chr12   HAVANA  gene    28133249        28581511        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000123106.9"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "CCDC91"                level   2       tag     "ncRNA_host"    havana_gene     "OTTHUMG00000169141.2"
```

When grouping on Perl, i can get $1 but not $2 and $3.
Any idea?

Comment: I need to take every entry, so without the or it's difficult

Comment: I think, perhaps, that you should go back a step and explain what you're actually trying to achieve here. You seem seem you have gone down a path that looks unhelpful and we might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: did you really want to search for "one or more word characters, followed by any single character (other than a newline), followed by one or more digits"?  that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the `|` operator so there's only 1 group captured in each option. So why should it capture `$2` and `$3`?

Comment: Thanks, i need to take everyone on the text and if remore the or it takes nothing, the or is the only way to get them all to me, maybe i'm missing something

Comment: Isn't that too generic? I'm asking for general help

Comment: @BlueStarry regular expressions are a large-scale tool (some might even say a language on it's own) that you need to learn it's basic building blocks thoroughly to use properly. I really encourage you to go back to these basics and sharpen them. If you need some training ground that will help you improve your skills in regex, here's a good one - https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably tackle this very differently. Can I suggest something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

#field names
my @desired_fields = qw ( gene_id transcript_id gene_name transcript_name );

while (<DATA>) {
   #match 'word' and 'quoted word' and select into a hash. 
   my %key_values = m/(\w+)\s+\"([^\"]+)\"/g;
   #print what we captured for debugging reasons:
   print Dumper \%key_values;

   #print line number
   print "Line: $.\n";
   #iterate @desired fields, print a line if it's defined. 
   for (@desired_fields) {
      print "$_ => $key_values{$_}\n" if defined $key_values{$_};
   }
}


__DATA__
chr1    HAVANA  exon    183647567       183647797       .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000173627.7"     transcript_id   "ENST00000481562.1"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "APOBEC4"       transcript_type "processed_transcript"  transcript_status       "KNOWN" transcript_name "APOBEC4-002"   exon_number     2       exon_id "ENSE00001907807.1"     level   2       transcript_support_level        "3"     havana_gene     "OTTHUMG00000035459.2"  havana_transcript       "OTTHUMT00000086127.1"
chr1    HAVANA  gene    183646404       183653316       .       -       .       gene_id "ENSG00000173627.7"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "APOBEC4"               level   2       havana_gene     “OTTHUMG00000035459.2”
chr12   HAVANA  gene    28133249        28581511        .       +       .       gene_id "ENSG00000123106.9"     gene_type       "protein_coding"        gene_status     "KNOWN" gene_name       "CCDC91"                level   2       tag     "ncRNA_host"    havana_gene     "OTTHUMG00000169141.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick up all the groups in one match, you have to wrap them in a non-capturing group and add a quantifier.  That means you also have to account for the fields you don't care about as well as the intervening whitespace.  This regex works for your sample:

```
(?:
  \h+
  (?:
    gene_id\h+"([^"]+)"         |
    transcript_id\h+"([^"]+)"   |
    gene_name\h+"([^"]+)"       |
    transcript_name\h+"([^"]+)" |
    \w+\h+\S+
  )
)+
$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/toNABN/1)

Note that this will match even if none of the fields that interest you are present.  If the `gene_id` field is required and always first, as it is in your sample, you can make the regex more precise as well as more efficient:

```
gene_id\h+"([^"]+)"
(?:
  \h+
  (?:
    transcript_id\h+"([^"]+)"   |
    gene_name\h+"([^"]+)"       |
    transcript_name\h+"([^"]+)" |
    \w+\h+\S+
  )
)+
$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/toNABN/2)